# Запрос на массовый UPDATE

Tags: mysql

может есть кто может подсказать в какую сторону смотреть?
Суть в чем, условно есть таблица вида id - title, в title у нас имеются записи вида артикул (аналог), сейчас хочу обновить все такие записи чтобы получить другой формат, а именно - артикул · (аналог), то есть во все title где есть приписка (аналог) докинуть среднюю точку перед скобками. Готового решения не прошу, просто куда копать подскажите, а то вообще ничерта не понятно

Comment: конкретный пример данных приведите

Comment: `replace` сделайте для `(аналог)` на `.(аналог)` или какая там точка у вас.

Comment: @teran о, спасибо, так просто не думал, мутил с подзапросами. Напиши в ответ, помечу как решение)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте replace для замены

```
 UPDATE tbl 
 SET x = replace(x, '(аналог)', '.(аналог)')
 WHERE x like '%(аналог)%'
```